# cakephp save array field (hasMany)

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an array field in the HTML:

```
< input type="text" name="WineDescripcion[Description][]" />
```

This field can be duplicated by clicking a button, How can I save it into the model trough the controller ?

This is my current code:

```
$this->Vino->VinoDescription->save($this->data);
```

But this returns an SQL error:

```
Query: INSERT INTO `vino_description` (`subtitulo`, `descripcion`, `id_vino`) VALUES (Array, Array, 60)
```

Also if I try to change the name in the HTML to:

```
< input type="text" name="WineDescripcion[][Description]" />
```

That works, but only saves 1 record with "NULL" values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: < input type="text" name="data[WineDescripcion][0][description]" />
< input type="text" name="data[WineDescripcion][1][description]" />
< input type="text" name="data[WineDescripcion][2][description]" />

iirc, that is the structure to use, and then with no other models in the data array use saveAll($this->data), no foreach just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle your post data in controller before inserting. You try to insert values as arrays. It isn't correct. Give not array values from post data. You can use `print_r($this->data)` to see what is your post data structure.

Comment: This is the output with the current field name:

WineDescripcion[][Subtitle]
WineDescripcion[][Description]

[VinoDescription] => Array
 (
  [0] => Array
   (
    [Subtitle] => Title 1
   )

  [1] => Array
   (
    [Description] => Description 1
   )

  [2] => Array
   (
    [Subtitle] => Title 2
   )

  [3] => Array
   (
    [Description] => Description 2
   )

 )

Answer (score 0):

This is how finally solve this:

```
    for ($i=0; $i<=count($this->data['VinoDescription'])-1; $i++) {
        $this->Vino->VinoDescription->create();
        $insertData = array('id_vino' => $this->Vino->id, 'subtitulo' => $this->data['VinoDescription']['subtitulo'][$i], 'descripcion' => $this->data['VinoDescription']['descripcion'][$i]);
        $this->Vino->VinoDescription->save($insertData);
    }
```

Thanks Alexander for the tips.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($this->data as $row) {
   $insertData = array('subtitle' => $row['Subtitle'], 'description' => $row['description']);
   $this->Vino->VinoDescription->save($insertData);
}
```

And maybe you have error in your syntax `subtitulo`, `descripcion`. Maybe it should be `subtitle` and `description`?

Comment: Undefined index, becouse it's s array for each element

Comment: the data wont be in $this->data as the field name is not data[Something]